# PHP Using both client side and server side validation WITHOUT using 3rd party code

Tags: php, javascript, validation

EDIT: thanks for all the help. Received an email saying that we didn't need the client side so I scrapped that idea in favor of actually completing the assignment on time.

Before you ask, Yes this is assignment work. No I am not looking for someones complete code. I am a beginner will practically no experience in HTML/PHP/javascript, but this is the second part of the assignment so I already have some of my own code from the first part, which was so very easy in comparison to this part. The task doesn't specifically say we have to use client side validation, but I feel it would be good practice.

I need someone to clearly show me how to use both client and server side validation. I already have the javascript validation, but I can modify it as it displays an alert box for every error. I CANNOT use 3rd party code like jQuery which apparently everyone on the internet likes to use, and the course I am doing doesn't like to actually teach us any useful content so we are all on our own.

The data from the form will then be entered into a database through MySQL (which I am not looking forward to doing), and from viewing the minimal information from w3schools on the topic, I understand that I have to POST the form to itself.

The form itself is pretty simple: contains name, DoB, email, postcode etc.
My current .js uses alpha only, num only, date format, email format, radio button and check box checks and every field is tested to make sure it isn't empty.

I suppose what I am after is a complete tutorial on how to do this. My internet searches have been unfruitful, but at least I still have a week till this is due.

Any help is appreciated, but simple and clear help would be even more so. I will continue to prowl the internet for help until then and post back here if I find useful stuff for anyone else with the same problem (which I'm sure is 90% of my class.....)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I CANNOT use 3rd party code like jQuery" - can you please define a reason for that. It seems important.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius It's homework.. I'm pretty sure the reason is they're teaching js, not a library for js.

Comment: [http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptform.php]

[http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=438]

Comment: That's a shame :( jQuery should be taught. It is sooo widely used nowadays.

Comment: Please read http://w3fools.com/ before relying on what they say.
The places to go are [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) and [PHP.net](http://PHP.net)

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius - it states very clearly in our task that we are not allowed to use 3rd party code. If we do we receive no marks for that section of the assignment.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the w3ools.com site. It's stupid how my university tells up to go learn from w3schools. it's not helpful in anyway shape or form. 
and, on that note, what i needed where it was all together, rather than separately, and it is hard to get that stuff without 3rd party code, even more so when my google searching skills are poor.

Comment: Well, the longer you work with something the faster you will find stuff on google, so just stick with your goals and if needed, SO will kindly help :) Best of luck and hopefully we'll see you active and successful :)

Answer (score 4):

Read the code below. Hope inline comments answer your question.

**add_record.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

  //get post data
  $name = trim($_POST['person_name']);
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $message = trim($_POST['message']);

  //This is server-side check!
  if (strlen($name) > 10){
    echo "FAILED! You tried to submit a name which is greater than 10 chars."
  }else{
    //insert to the database here..

    //and send out a "success message or render HTML
    echo "SUCCESS!";
  }
}else {
    echo "Error! Proper parameters were not provided!";
}
```

**a.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(){
    //client side (JS) validation. This happens before submitting.
    var name = document.forms[0].person_name.value;
    if (name.length > 10){
        alert("Name is too long");
        return false;
    }
    //do some more checks here..
    //return true if all checks have passed, false otherwise.

    //the return value of this function is checked before submit. The form is submitted only when this function returns a true.
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="add_record.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
Name: <input type="text" name="person_name"/>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
Message: <input type="text" name="message"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: As  mplungjan pointed out, it is not a good idea to have a field named "name" inside forms. The form object itself might have a "name" which might conflict.

Comment: Okay, well while that confuses the hell out of me, it actually seems pretty simple to implement both. Thanks for that. I'll give it a try when I'm done with the more pressing assignments.

Comment: In that case try having PHP section in a separate file. Or wait I will update my post.

Comment: @Thrustmaster - please a) pass the form using `return checkForm(this)` and b) please do not use `name` as a field name since a form may also have a name.

Comment: Yes, about the 'name' part, I agree. But why must I pass a reference of the form when I know its the only form in the HTML?

Comment: Because then it will always work, even when you decide to add a search form to the top of the page - and it will make the script less cluttered. formObj.firstName is nicer than document.forms[0].firstName

Comment: i like this answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since it's homework, I should at least point you to a few resources:

**Client side**

For validation:

- http://www.9lessons.info/2009/03/perfect-javascript-form-validation.html (form validator)
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml (regular expression guide)

Don't jump to AJAX straight away, that's advanced material. Get the basics done first and just let the form submit to PHP (i.e. page refreshes and PHP redraws the form if there were any validation issues).

**Server side**

For validation: http://www.php.net/filter - [examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)

For database work: http://www.php.net/pdo - [tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)

Comment: Is `filter` part of the standard PHP package? On PHP.net it tells me to install it

Comment: @mplungjan It's typically enabled on PHP builds

Answer (score 0):

For server side validation, you would send the form data to a php page using method="post", then check for correct format. Something like:

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
<!-- form fields -->
</form>
```

In validate.php, you use $_POST["var_name"], where var_name is the name of your input fields, to check the data. So, for example, something like:

```
$age = $_POST["age"];
if (ctype_digit($age) && $age > 0) {
    // correct format
}
```

It seems like you already have client side validation figured out. I'm not quite sure if I understood your problem correctly, though - Let me know where specifically you are having problems and I'll try to help.

Comment: It's more that I don't really understand how they fit together. I'm sure that I can get both working independently but I don't understand how to use them in conjunction.