# How do i check the input text against database value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, validation

this is the codes I currently have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include ("dbFunctions.php");


$query = "SELECT * FROM ten_eleven_twelve";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Times Table Game
    </title>

<center>
    <h1>Game Play - HARD</h1>
    <div class="border_solid">
        <div id="timer"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</center>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/hard.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $questID = $row['ten_eleven_twelve_id'];
        $factor1 = $row['factor1'];
        $factor2 = $row['factor2'];
        $answer = $row['answer'];
        ?>
        <form action="demo_form.asp">
            <div class="image-questionid"><u>Question <?php echo $questID; ?></u></div>
            <input type="text" class="factor1" name="factor1"><br>
            <div class="image-betweenfactor">X</div>
            <input type="text" class="factor2" name="factor2"><br>
            <div class="image-questionequals">=</div>
            <div class="image-answer"><?php echo $answer; ?></div>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </form>

        <?php
        break;
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar = setInterval(function () {
        myTimer()
    }, 1000);
    var d = 0;
    function myTimer() {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d++;
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically I want the user to input the values inside the textbox and then I'll have to validate the textbox by checking the values of the textbox to the database. Anyone can show me the codes on how it should be done? :)

I have changed into this checking method, what is wrong with it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include ("dbFunctions.php");


$query = "SELECT * FROM ten_eleven_twelve";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Times Table Game
    </title>

<center>
    <h1>Game Play - HARD</h1>
    <div class="border_solid">
        <div id="timer"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</center>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/hard.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $questID = $row['ten_eleven_twelve_id'];
        $factor1 = $row['factor1'];
        $factor2 = $row['factor2'];
        $answer = $row['answer'];
        ?>
        <form method="post" onsubmit="validate()">
            <div class="image-questionid"><u>Question <?php echo $questID; ?></u></div>
            <input type="text" class="factor1" id="factor1" name="factor1"><br>
            <div class="image-betweenfactor">X</div>
            <input type="text" class="factor2" id="factor2" name="factor2"><br>
            <div class="image-questionequals">=</div>
            <div class="image-answer"><?php echo $answer; ?></div>
            <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </form>

        <?php
        break;
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar = setInterval(function () {
        myTimer()
    }, 1000);

    var d = 0;
    function myTimer() {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d++;
    }

    function validate() {
        var factor1 = document.getElementById('factor1').value;
        var factor2 = document.getElementById('factor2').value;
        if (factor1 === $row['factor1'] && factor1 === $row['factor2']) {
            var msg = "There is a problem with the Registration form";
            alert(msg);
            return true;
        } else {
            alert(msg);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how it possible? factor1 === $row['factor1']???

Comment: ist of clear one thing, where do u want validation server side or client side?

Comment: i want it to validate the server side after the client has input his values in the text box

Comment: its not on server side... function validate() { its javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716436/php-using-both-client-side-and-server-side-validation-without-using-3rd-party-co

Comment: I'm not good at understanding.. I need it to be done for me to look into it.. :(

Comment: you're closing your db connection to early.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(factor1,factor2) VALUES(:factor1,:factor2)"); 
$stmt->execute(array(':factor1' => $_POST['factor1'],':factor2' => $_POST['factor2']));
```

Look here tutorial http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: where is this suppose to be put into? @Knase

Comment: sorry, but i've edited the headers to checking against the database value.. am i suppose to do an INSERT?